# Failed to generate preview for user -- Facebook android SDK 4.2

Tags: android, facebook

I'm currently working on sharing a place on facebook.

Here's my code

```
// Create an object
            ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
                    .putString("og:type", "anewplace")
                    .putString("og:title", "Paris")
                    .putDouble("place:location:latitude", 10.7672788)
                    .putDouble("place:location:longitude", 106.6877127)
                    .build();

            // Create an action
            ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
                    .setActionType("come")
                    .putObject("anewplace", object)
                    .build();

            // Create the content
            ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
                    .setPreviewPropertyName("anewplace")
                    .setAction(action)
                    .build();


            ShareButton shareButton = new ShareButton(this);
            shareButton.setShareContent(content);
            shareButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "SHARING SUCCESS!");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "SHARING ERROR! - " + error.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Log.w(TAG, "SHARING CANCEL!");
                }
            });

            shareButton.performClick();
```

I got an error : Failed to generate preview for user

I followed the documentation to create a custom story

Please help :) thanks

Thanh

Answer (score 0):

i found the way :)

for the action, it should be this format "app_name:action_name"
and for the object, it should be "app_name:object_name"